# Better colors for bronze and silver badges

Tags: feature-request

I think it's extremely hard to see the difference between silver and bronze when looking at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges

It sure isn't the biggest issue in the world, and maybe I'm slightly colour blind, but it bugs me. Wouldn't it be possible to maybe make the bronze slightly darker? It could also work with making the circles a bit bigger. Another approach is having different sizes for the circles, or even different shapes.

[image: Colours]

It's actually quite remarkable how much easier it is to see on a bigger surface. However, in my opinion it's still not enough of a difference. Note that I don't think the bigger circles look good. They only serve the purpose to show the difference in difficulty of distinguishing the colours at different circle sizes.

Here is a suggestion that's inspired by Kyle Williamson below

[image: shapes]

Comment: Yeah, I'd say it is slight colour blindness, as they REALLY look different to me (one is clearly brown-ish while the other is gray). But yeah, I can see how they could potentially look the same.

Comment: I don't have any trouble seeing the difference between the colors either, but I've always thought they should look more shiny, so just thought I'd bring that up while we're at it.

Comment: I don't struggle with seeing the different colors if I'm looking right at them, but when I'm glancing over the list it would be nice to be able to see them more quickly without having to focus on every one and still discern the color

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the color icons at the top of the screen?

Comment: @Icepickle Not as much, but at that place there's also no problem. There are at most three of them, and I know the order. :)

Comment: I've also never had an issue and since the badges are ordered left to right: gold, silver, bronze its easy to tell what represents what. Going off what @Don'tPanic said about adding a shine, I think it would be cool if the colors were given a slight illuminated effect!

Comment: @ob1 except... I was kinda kidding

Comment: @Don'tPanic welp ok XD

Comment: Wow, I rarely look at the badges but having looked now, the bronze and silver definitely look similar (I AM colourblind though, maybe that is why?). It doesn't bother me that much as I personally don't look at badges but I also think that it won't hurt to make the colours stand out a little better.

Answer (score 13):

I can see how people could struggle to see the difference at first glance, especially on the black backgrounds.  I am sure the balance being off on computer screens is a common issue.

---

> Wouldn't it be possible to maybe make the bronze slightly darker?

Changing the brown seems to help a bit.

> It could also work with making the circles a bit bigger.

I personally don't think larger circles look very attractive.
I think the best solution (if this is actually an issue for enough people) would be to change the shapes.

[image: Changed badge tags]

Comment: Believe it or not. I was sitting in gimp right this second, and those shapes were just what I had in mind!

Comment: But I think that silver should just a tiny bit smaller and gold a tiny bit bigger.

Comment: @klutt I agree.  Sadly, I only had paint installed so I did the best I could.

Comment: Since you had come further in the process I used your image to create a new one.

Comment: Shapes is not really an option though, since every sister site has it's own shapes already. You  might just run out of them if you start using 3 shapes per site.

Comment: @mast what sister sites do doesn't really effect what SO does.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Doing it here and not there would lead to fixing the problem here and not there. That's fixing one problem and leaving 299 or so (not sure what the count is nowadays) problems open.

Comment: @mast perhaps - but that is for them to decide how to approach. They may decide on a variety of solutions (or none), not just changing shapes. To solve SO's issue, I think this is great.

Comment: What about adjusting the text color to match the badge color?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I like these colours just the way they are, and would not want them changed.

You could try adjusting your computer screen; perhaps the colour balance is off. The two colours are really quite different. I can't actually think of a common form of colour blindness that would explain confusing the two.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I remember it correctly it is like that on all monitors I'm using. (A total of 6)

Comment: @klutt: Are they all black & white? :)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure. Need to check that too. :D

Comment: Colorblind here. Any colorblindness effects color certainty and comparison. I'm red/green and these badges are hard to delineate between. Make a colorblind user adjust color balance (which is likely calibrated already) v. accomodate by increasing contrast. Second option sounds good to me.

Comment: Well, there is color blindness where those two can look similar Achromatopsia, look at bottom of the page [Bronze](http://www.colorhexa.com/d1a684)

Comment: @Dalija: I see!

Comment: I'm surprised this is useful enough to get upvotes. The question regards the ability to see a distinction between colors, not a mere preference. That's nice for you all that the badge colors are pretty, but hardly constructive. Red and Green are also "rather quite different" and are in fact complementary colors, so are about as different as visual colors get, yet there are people with red-green color blindness. Simply not being able to "_think of_ a common form of colorblindness" is hardly a good answer unless you're an expert in the field.  I'm glad Dalija could help jog your memory.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar that's an interesting resource, but with that the gold colour also looks silver: http://www.colorhexa.com/ffcc01.

Comment: Achromotopsia only affects 0.0033% of the population, hardly a "common form of colour blindness". Distinguishing between silver and bronze badges would likely be the least of a sufferer's problems.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Well, yes. I was merely correcting the wrong assumption that those two colors are distinguishable by all people. While wording was "__common__ form of colour blindness", it can be easily translated to __any__ if you don't read carefully or you are not native English speaker.